# XAMPP - Apache Error

Tags: apache, xampp

This is the error I get when I try to start Apache.

[image]
[image]

The error logs are :

```
 [ssl:warn] [pid 7132:tid 392] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
 [ssl:warn] [pid 7132:tid 392] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
 [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7132:tid 392] AH00455: Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.5.15 configured -- resuming normal operations
 [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7132:tid 392] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Jul 17 2014 11:50:08
 [core:notice] [pid 7132:tid 392] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
 [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7132:tid 392] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 540
 [ssl:warn] [pid 540:tid 408] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
 [ssl:warn] [pid 540:tid 408] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
 [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 540:tid 408] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

I don't understand what the problem is. Can anyone help?

I have changed the Ports in the below lines in the httpd.conf file

```
Listen 80
ServerName localhost:80
```

Are there any other files where I need to change these values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It worked when i run the XAMPP control panel with administrator rights.

Answer (score 0):

You only have to change the port in the httpd.conf 
 
try:

```
netstat -ano
```

and check if Port 80 is not used by another Program.
Close the Program which uses port 80 and try to start apache again.

Comment: well. i changed the port to 78 which isn't being used by any other program. I still get the error.

Comment: what was the default value of ServerName? localhost or localhost:80? i don't have a httpd.conf here to check it, but i thought the right value is just **localhost** or **127.0.0.1**

Comment: It was localhost:80 originally.