# XAMPP Error: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

Tags: php, xampp, ssl-certificate

I am running XAMPP and have rebuilt my PHP server from the ground up, renamed the server from `ServerV1` to `ServerV2`, and now attempting a basic POST request from Android volley, returns the error found within the Apache logs:

```
[Sat Dec 19 19:24:57.528601 2015] [core:notice] [pid 7956:tid 260] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Sat Dec 19 19:24:57.531601 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7956:tid 260] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 5784
[Sat Dec 19 19:24:58.047631 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 5784:tid 272] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Dec 19 19:24:58.290645 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 5784:tid 272] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Dec 19 19:24:58.325647 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5784:tid 272] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

I am not listening on any used ports:

[image]

I have research others simply running as an administrator in sources like: https://teamtreehouse.com/community/solved-xampp-apache-error  and
[XAMPP - Apache Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26928989/xampp-apache-error)

Upon attempting that, it still does not work, where the only return from any POST is a `0`.

NOTE: I have tested every action with google chromes POSTMAN and know my routes do work and return the proper JSON objects.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client-short/mkhojklkhkdaghjjfdnphfphiaiohkef?hl=en

What steps can I take to alleviate this issue?

Comment: Maybe it has to do with config? Is this `example.com` only a placeholder? Because if it says that it tries to get the certificate from there, it should fail, because the certificate presumably is on localhost?

Comment: How can the certificate be configured to match the server name?

Comment: Well I cannot say for sure. It could be related to Apache and/or PHP or to the communication with your Android volley. If volley is newer it might use something that your outdated version of XAMPP, especially the Apache and PHP version do not offer. Maybe you could update your XAMPP? If this does not help, here might be another hint: https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=6662

Comment: I am using XAMPP version 1.8.3. That cannot be the issue because I can successfully send requests using POSTMAN, and they all return successfully

Comment: You get this going?  I'm having the same issue and I've tried tons of similar supposed solutions from people with similar issues.  This one seemed the most promising if you want to try another one (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30758894/apache-server-xampp-doesnt-run-on-windows-10-port-80/31229606#32259668), but it didn't work for me.

Comment: The solution essentially ended up being that I had a space in the URL IP address on the POST request I was sending, very minor oversight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just shutdown that application which is using 443 port & retry. mine vmware workstation was using 443 port i just kill process tree of vmware & retried it works for me.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

1. Open `httpd-ssl.conf` here:

   ```
   C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra
   ```
2. Comment out the line and change it to `localhost`

   ```
   #ServerName www.example.com:443
   ServerName localhost
   ```
3. And of course restart your Apache

Comment: this does not work for me

Comment: Make sure this (`localhost`) matches the common name (`CN`) or an entry in `SubjectAltName` in the certificate you use

Answer (score 3):

Try just by commenting ***Listen 443*** (like #Listen 443)in ***httpd-ssl.conf*** file. it will Work 100%. Mine site it has work 100%.

Comment: this solution  did not work for me

Comment: This solution will disable the https server on port 443.

Answer (score 3):

i know this is late but i've found the answer... Apparently you have to right click on the xampp-control.exe file and run it as administrator, and then probably it works perfectly now! that worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me, although I'm not sure what changed because it was working fine on normal execution a few days ago... now all of a sudden I have to run as administrator for the scripts to load. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue after copying my xampp folder from windows 7 to another installation of windows 10.

Have tried the solutions listed here, but none worked for me. I had no time to try other solutions so I just made a new installation from scratch

Answer (score 0):

installing new xampp (7.3.16) works for me

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27904823)

Comment: I do think this does provide answer @k.s FROM REVIEW GUY, the user has just written what worked for him/her

Answer (score 0):

This is possible due to **DocumentRoot** path have not set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I solved it. The reason for me was because port 8080 was in use. I found it by running "netstat -ab" in the command prompt in administrator mode. Then I changed the port (From both xampp config and httpd.conf) for something else and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, none of the above solutions worked. So, I decided to uninstall XAMPP and other software like TeamViewer and Terabox. What I did was uninstall all these programs, restart my PC, and then install XAMPP. It worked like a charm! It's possible that some other software was using the port that XAMPP needed.