# Switching PHP version on XAMPP localhost causes Apache to crash

Tags: php, apache, xampp, localhost

I have the latest version of XAMPP and PHP installed on my localhost server. But I have a website which is built in PHP 7.2.3 and the website's scripts generate errors when run on the localhost because the website won't work in PHP 8.

I changed my localhost PHP version from 8 to 7.2.3 but now XAMPP gives me an error when I start Apache. The error is:

> Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly. This may be due to a blocked
> port, missing dependencies,  improper privileges, a crash, or a
> shutdown by another method. Press the Logs button to view error logs
> and check the Windows Event Viewer for more clues If you need more
> help, copy and post this entire log window on the forums

Comment: So, Press the Logs button to view error logs. It's hard to tell without an error log, as mentioned, it may be because a lot of reasons.

Comment: [Thu Feb 29 01:08:11.342137 2024] [ssl:warn] [pid 3324:tid 452] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Feb 29 01:08:11.427065 2024] [ssl:warn] [pid 3324:tid 452] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Feb 29 01:08:11.503830 2024] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3324:tid 452] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XAMPP Error: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376916/xampp-error-www-example-com4430-server-certificate-does-not-include-an-id-whi)

Comment: no bro actually my issue is i changed my php version then apache server didnot work

Comment: v7.2.3 of PHP was release in 2018. Please update your application to use a supported version of PHP, or even the latest version of the 7.2 series. Also, share more details from your log file

Comment: Try and open the folder where the `httpd.exe` is located, in a `cmd` terminal or Windows PowerShell, and then execute the file in there - I found that that sometimes gives additional information about startup errors, that you won't find in the logs.

Comment: The problem may be to do with the XAMPP configuration as mentioned [here](https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?t=80366&p=271722). Mismatches to do with the SSL certificate cause a warning but do not normally cause a crash. It sounds like the PHP version switching in XAMPP is not working as expected and PHP 8 libraries are being loaded into a PHP 7 environment.