# Apache doesn't work on XAMPP

Tags: apache, ssl, xampp

This is the error.log:

> [Tue Feb 02 17:52:21.354153 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 3968:tid 516] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
>   [Tue Feb 02 17:52:21.688158 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 3968:tid 516] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
>   [Tue Feb 02 17:52:21.849447 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3968:tid 516] AH00455: Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2e PHP/7.0.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
>   [Tue Feb 02 17:52:21.849947 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3968:tid 516] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Dec  9 2015 10:17:39
>   [Tue Feb 02 17:52:21.849947 2016] [core:notice] [pid 3968:tid 516] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
>   [Tue Feb 02 17:52:21.855326 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3968:tid 516] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 1036
>   [Tue Feb 02 17:52:22.903485 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 1036:tid 540] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
>   [Tue Feb 02 17:52:23.070726 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 1036:tid 540] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
>   [Tue Feb 02 17:52:23.098750 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1036:tid 540] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26928989/xampp-apache-error

Comment: @MCMXCII already done that and it doesn't workk

Comment: I would guess the certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name. But that's purely a guess based in the limited info you've provided. Other than that you'll need to give a LOT more detail and config. What doesn't work? Apache crashes? Apache is running but the website doesn't show in the browser? If so what's the browser error? The http version works but not the https version doesn't show? You get a cert error when you go to it in the browser? Something else?